iOS browsers reload WebGL games (built with Unity) on big loading events that do not allocate RAM
We've built a WebGL game with Unity and it runs fine everywhere except on iOS browsers.
For simplicity of understanding and referencing, I'll write down noteworthy points in number-point format:

Game has 2 scenes. One is UI-only and the other full of 3D and vfx. Game reloads during the 2nd scene at a random time.
We pre-allocate all memory we'll need. That's 1GB. We've observed that the game does not reach that limit during that loading event. Not on any platform including iOS.
Prior to adding a lot of new VFX, the issue would not happen.

